# Can I use offer code while having an active subscription in Apple in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

We like to share some gift cards to subscribers using offer codes(1month free).
if user don't have an active subscription, I understand the user will get the first subscription period free, then they will pay actual cost. But if the user already have an active subscription, will he able to use the offer code?